# Compose FunctionK by foldMap

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have two free-monad algebra `DomainOp` and `DbOp`

```
type DbFree[A] = Free[DbOp, A]
```

I have written two interpreters. One for `DomainOp ~> DbFree` and one for `DbOp ~> Task`. I want to combine the interpreters so I can have an interpreter `DomainOp ~> Task`. Is there an existing operation in Cats for composing two interpreters where the operation is a foldMap over the second interpreter? I can write something like below, but I'm interested if something like this already exists as it feels like a common use case for free monad API.

```
  implicit class FreeFunctionKOps[F[_], G[_]](fk: FunctionK[F, ({ type L[H] = Free[G, H] })#L]) {
    def foldMapCompose[I[_]](fk2: FunctionK[G, I])(implicit I: Monad[I]): FunctionK[F, I] =
      new FunctionK[F, I] {
        override def apply[A](fa: F[A]): I[A] = fk(fa).foldMap(fk2)
      }
  }
```

Comment: You could use `Free.foldMap` which turns an `F ~> G` into a `Free[F, ?] ~> G`.

Comment: @PeterNeyens that's exactly what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Peter Neyens: You could use `cats.free.Free.foldMap` which turns an `F ~> G` into a `Free[F, ?] ~> G`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a `DbFree ~> DbOp` and compose it with your two existing `FunctionKs`:

```
val f1: DomainOp ~> DbFree ...
val f2: DbOp ~> Task = ...
vla f3: DbFree ~> DbOp = new (DbFree ~> DbOp) {
  def apply[X](x: DbFree[X]): DbOp[X] = x.foldMap(FunctionK.id)
} // Or FunctionK.lift(_.foldMap(FunctionK.id))

f1 andThen f3 andThen f3
```